# Using python on android tablet

Tags: android, python

Learning python workflow on android tablet

I have been using Qpython3 but find it unsatisfactory

Can anybody tell me how best to learn the python workflow using an android tablet... that is what IDE works best with android and any links to pertinent information. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try pydroid3 instead of Qpython.it have almost all scientific Python libraries like Numpy,scikit-learn,matplotlib,pandas etc.All you have to do is to download the scripting library.You can save your file with extension ' .py ' and then upload it to drive and then to colab

Hope this will help.......

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Android tablet specific IDE for coding and learning python.  I looked into coding on a mobile device a while back, and decided that server based in-browser workflow was best, in terms of development and user experience.  Maybe you've looked into these already, but here's two options:

> *PythonAnywhere* running on an iPad (and Android)  https://www.pythonanywhere.com/
>
> *Google CoLab* https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb

With CoLab, you just need a browser and a modern device.  Some person said he codes only on an Android phone, because he doesn't have a computer.  It stores all your python setup and libraries, and data on Google's server, and serves the jupyter notebooks to you.  I think you need to use jupyter notebooks as an interface when coding on it.  You can link your Google Drive to store data too (mount it to your Colab account).

Between the two options, I prefer Google Colab, because I use Jupyter Notebooks a lot.  But if you are writing python games, then Python Anywhere is far better.  The interface is more like a traditional IDE.

Comment: Thanks Jennifer ... I liked your answer. Have a great day.

Comment: Glad I could help!  We, newbies, need to help each other out when we can. :-)

Comment: Do you think a good data analyst can win in the financial (stock) markets?

Comment: It's extremely difficult to "win" in the stock market over the long-term.  Generally buy and hold beats almost all methods, because cost and your time & effort needs to be part of the consideration.  Go look at Sentdex guy at pythonprogramming.net.  His Q&A videos answer this question for him.